# JavaScript: Position DIV Centered Above Text Selection?

Tags: javascript, html, getboundingclientrect

I am trying to position a `<div>` above a users text selection that will act as a toolbar similar to Mediums.

[image]

While I have successfully gotten the `<div>` to be positioned next to the selection, I cannot seem to get it to correctly center relative to the selection:

```
    $(function() {
      // Setup the Event Listener
      $('.article').on('mouseup', function() {
        // Selection Related Variables
        let selection = window.getSelection(),
        getRange      = selection.getRangeAt(0),
        selectionRect = getRange.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Set the Toolbar Position
        $('.toolbar').css({
          top: selectionRect.top - 42 + 'px',
          left: selectionRect.left + 'px'
        });
      });
    });
```

I can determine the selection's center point by subtracting the selections left offset from the viewport by its width as such:

```
 selectionRect.left - selectionRect.width
```

However, I am not sure how to use that to set the position of my toolbar to be centered relative to the selection rectangle?

I tried subtracting the toolbars left offset from the width of the selection divided by 2 but that doesn't align to the center perfectly either.

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/e64jLd0o/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution would be to add the following to your CSS:

```
.toolbar {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

and update your script to offset the left position of the toolbar element like so:

```
$('.toolbar').css({
  top: selectionRect.top - 42 + 'px',
  left: ( selectionRect.left + (selectionRect.width * 0.5)) + 'px'
});
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  // Setup the Event Listener
  $('.article').on('mouseup', function() {
    // Selection Related Variables
    let selection = window.getSelection(),
    getRange      = selection.getRangeAt(0),
    selectionRect = getRange.getBoundingClientRect();
     

    // Set the Toolbar Position
    $('.toolbar').css({
      top: selectionRect.top - 42 + 'px',
      left: ( selectionRect.left + (selectionRect.width * 0.5)) + 'px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.article {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 169px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Editor -->
<div class="article">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur dignissimos facilis id repellat sint deserunt voluptates animi eaque tempore debitis, perferendis repudiandae voluptatem. Eligendi fuga deleniti saepe quod eum voluptas.</p>
</div>

<!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="toolbar">Toolbar</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

For a quick edit, I applied the changes required to position the div correctly:

https://jsfiddle.net/yaLvzswu/

I applied some additional positioning math on the `left` calculation:

```
$(function() {
  // Setup the Event Listener
  $('.article').on('mouseup', function() {
    // Selection Related Variables
    let selection = window.getSelection(),
    getRange      = selection.getRangeAt(0),
    selectionRect = getRange.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(selectionRect)
    // Set the Toolbar Position
    $('.toolbar').css({
      top: selectionRect.top - 42 + 'px',
      left: (selectionRect.left - ($('.toolbar').width()/2) + (selectionRect.width/2))+ 'px'
    });
  });
});
```

Your version applied the left of the toolbar to the left of the selected text. As we want to put the *centre* of your toolbar to the *centre* of the selection, the left is shuffled twice:

- start left
- move left by half the toolbar width

Now the toolbar centre is on the left of selection.

- add half the selection width

The toolbar moves right a bit - centre of selected text.